# Pyspark SQL: using case when statements

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame which looks like  this

```
>>> df_w_cluster.select('high_income', 'aml_cluster_id').show(10)
+-----------+--------------+
|high_income|aml_cluster_id|
+-----------+--------------+
|          0|             0|
|          0|             0|
|          0|             1|
|          0|             1|
|          0|             0|
|          0|             0|
|          0|             1|
|          1|             1|
|          1|             0|
|          1|             0|
+-----------+--------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

The `high_income` column is a binary column and hold either `0` or `1`. The `aml_cluster_id` holds values starting from `0` upto `3`. I want to create a new column whose values depend on the values of the `high_income` and `aml_cluster_id` in that particular row. I am trying to achieve this using SQL.

```
df_w_cluster.createTempView('event_rate_holder')
```

To accomplish this, I have written a query like so -

```
q = """select * , case 
 when "aml_cluster_id" = 0 and  "high_income" = 1 then "high_income_encoded" = 0.162 else 
 when "aml_cluster_id" = 0 and  "high_income" = 0 then "high_income_encoded" = 0.337 else 
 when "aml_cluster_id" = 1 and  "high_income" = 1 then "high_income_encoded" = 0.049 else 
 when "aml_cluster_id" = 1 and  "high_income" = 0 then "high_income_encoded" = 0.402 else 
 when "aml_cluster_id" = 2 and  "high_income" = 1 then "high_income_encoded" = 0.005 else 
 when "aml_cluster_id" = 2 and  "high_income" = 0 then "high_income_encoded" = 0.0 else 
 when "aml_cluster_id" = 3 and  "high_income" = 1 then "high_income_encoded" = 0.023 else 
 when "aml_cluster_id" = 3 and  "high_income" = 0 then "high_income_encoded" = 0.022 else 
 from event_rate_holder"""
```

when I run it in spark using

```
spark.sql(q)
```

I get the following error

```
mismatched input 'aml_cluster_id' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 22)
```

Any idea how to overcome this?

**EDIT**:

I edited the query according to the suggestion in the comments to the following

```
q = """select * , case 
when aml_cluster_id = 0 and  high_income = 1 then high_income_encoded = 0.162 else 
when aml_cluster_id = 0 and  high_income = 0 then high_income_encoded = 0.337 else 
when aml_cluster_id = 1 and  high_income = 1 then high_income_encoded = 0.049 else 
when aml_cluster_id = 1 and  high_income = 0 then high_income_encoded = 0.402 else 
when aml_cluster_id = 2 and  high_income = 1 then high_income_encoded = 0.005 else 
when aml_cluster_id = 2 and  high_income = 0 then high_income_encoded = 0.0 else 
when aml_cluster_id = 3 and  high_income = 1 then high_income_encoded = 0.023 else 
when aml_cluster_id = 3 and  high_income = 0 then high_income_encoded = 0.022 end
from event_rate_holder"""
```

but I am still getting errors

```
== SQL ==
select * , case 
when aml_cluster_id = 0 and  high_income = 1 then high_income_encoded = 0.162 else 
-----^^^
```

followed by

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: "\nmismatched input 'aml_cluster_id' expecting <EOF>(line 2, pos 5)\n\n== SQL ==\nselect * ,
```

Comment: Unrelated question, how did you import data?

Comment: Do you have newline characters in your query string? Try doing `q = q.replace("\n", " ")` before executing the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for the `CASE` variant you use is

```
CASE  
   WHEN e1 THEN e2 [ ...n ]   
   [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
END
```

So

- Then should be followed by expression. There is no place for `name = something` there.
- `ELSE` is allowed once per `CASE`, not after each `WHEN`.
- Your original code is missing closing `END`
- Finally columns shouldn't be quoted

You probably meant

```sql
CASE 
  WHEN aml_cluster_id = 0 AND high_income = 1 THEN 0.162
  WHEN aml_cluster_id = 0 and  high_income = 0 THEN  0.337
  ...
END AS high_income_encoded
```

Answer (score 1):

You would *need case end for each when conditions* in the query. and you would *need back tick for the column names* (`) and`high_income_encoded` column names *should be aliased at the end*. So the correct query is as following

```
q = """select * ,
case when `aml_cluster_id` = 0 and  `high_income` = 1 then 0.162 else
  case when `aml_cluster_id` = 0 and  `high_income` = 0 then 0.337 else
    case when `aml_cluster_id` = 1 and  `high_income` = 1 then 0.049 else
      case when `aml_cluster_id` = 1 and  `high_income` = 0 then 0.402 else
        case when `aml_cluster_id` = 2 and  `high_income` = 1 then 0.005 else
          case when `aml_cluster_id` = 2 and  `high_income` = 0 then 0.0 else
            case when `aml_cluster_id` = 3 and  `high_income` = 1 then 0.023 else
              case when `aml_cluster_id` = 3 and  `high_income` = 0 then 0.022
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end as `high_income_encoded`
from event_rate_holder"""
```

Comment: didn't the answer help ?

Comment: I have tried the answer given by Ramesh ans its working absolutely fine!! Thanks.